# div vision toggle from drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I'm creating a universal text template tool for work and I need a little help with getting the appropriate template to show up when a drop down menu is changed.

I'm using JavaScript, no JQuery for me yet.

The template objects are divs, and they are supposed to change by setting `display: none` on all but the one the menu has selected.

The problem: The templates (divs) never change.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7ATg/)

Thank you for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with the script.

Problems 
1. `caseSelect` was pointing to the object instead of value (`var caseSelect = document.getElementById("caseType").value;`)
2. In the `select` element all options had the value `thing1`
3. `break` statement was missing at the end of each `case`

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7ATg/2/)

Comment: Ack, that was sloppy of me. >.< Thank you for the help.